# vscode terminal requires me to add ./ before .exe files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before when I wanted to execute a `.exe` file that is found in the same directory that I am in, I would just do `nameoffile.exe`.

Now, I have to add this `./`

So I have to do `./nameoffile.exe`

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure it is using the same terminal you're used to i.e. if you're used to cmd make sure it is not using powershell instead (this should be shown in the top right corner of the terminal panel)